# How to make a queryset also contain a PK in django when returning JsonResponse

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got this model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='username')
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(default="none")
    replyto = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # maybe add ability to update comments...
    indent = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

On which i've got to return a queryset like this for creating a JsonResponse:

```
Comment.objects.filter(video_id=Video.objects.get(identifier=request.GET['identifier'])).order_by('-uploaded')[:end]
```

I get this as a response (after having serialized it to json and send it as response to a Ajax request.):

```
Object { user: "TestUser", video: 7, description: "test new video comment lol", replyto: 5, uploaded: "2018-01-12T09:14:24.281Z", updated: "2018-01-12T09:14:24.281Z", indent: 0 }
Object { user: "admin", video: 7, description: "testing the new comment system per …", replyto: null, uploaded: "2018-01-12T09:14:05.740Z", updated: "2018-01-12T09:14:05.740Z", indent: 0 }
```

However i'd like to include the PK of each object in the list of values. So I tried:

```
Comment.objects.value_list('pk','user','video','description','replyto','uploaded','updated','indent').filter(video_id=Video.objects.get(identifier=request.GET['identifier'])).order_by('-uploaded')[:end]
```

which caused the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'value_list'
```

why is this? how can I get a queryset which also includes the PK?

**EDIT**

as requested: here is the code for serializing the object:

```
def obtain_comments(request, *args, **kwargs):
    begin = int(request.GET['begin'])
    end = int(request.GET['end'])
    # check if end is less than number of comments and begin is more or equal than 0
    n_comments = end - begin
    all_split = Comment.objects.filter(video_id=Video.objects.get(identifier=request.GET['identifier'])).order_by('-uploaded')[:end]
    data = {
        'comments': serializers.serialize('json',all_split),
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Did you mean `values_list` ?

Comment: I tried values_list and I get: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: You should show *how* you're serializing the original queryset to JSON, since that appears to be the source of the issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added it

Comment: That's not your original code; you can't pass `values_list` to `serialize`. You need to show the actual code that gave you a serialized result without the PK.

Comment: Plus, you can't pass an already-serialized string to JsonResponse; and also, `serialize` does not format in the way you claim, as it puts the data inside a `fields` object within each item. So you need to show the code you are *actually* using.

Comment: this is the actuall code I'm using. ont the javascript side i use: `console.log(array[i].fields)` to print all the fields. here array is the list of objects i get from the response

Comment: on the first comment though you're right. I've removed the part that wasn't there before... sorry bout that

Comment: Well, the `pk` is passed in the parent object for each item.

Comment: ohh damm... your right...

Answer (score 0):

You can send field list to serializers.serialize. Then your code would be:

```
def obtain_comments(request, *args, **kwargs):
    begin = int(request.GET['begin'])
    end = int(request.GET['end'])
    # check if end is less than number of comments and begin is more or equal than 0
    n_comments = end - begin
    all_split = Comment.objects.filter(video__identifier=request.GET['identifier']).order_by('-uploaded')[:end]
    data = {
        'comments': serializers.serialize('json', all_split, fields=(
            'pk', 'user', 'video', 'description', 'replyto', 'uploaded', 'updated', 'indent'))
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but the question got answered in the comments of the question itself allready. I've had this answer before but it got deleted...